# Java DecimalFormat rounding error?

Tags: java, decimalformat

There seems to be some inconsistency with the way `DecimalFormat` rounds numbers.

`new DecimalFormat("0.0", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US)).format(number)`

Here's what's returned for some different `number` values.

- 0.05 returns 0.0
- 0.15 returns 0.2
- 0.25 returns 0.2
- 0.35 returns 0.4
- 0.45 returns 0.4

Why does this happen? And more importantly, how can I get the correct values (0.3 when rounding 0.25 and 0.5 when rounding 0.45)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javadoc states:

> DecimalFormat provides rounding modes defined in RoundingMode for formatting. By default, it uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN.

`HALF_EVEN` does exactly what you've noticed: it prefers rounding to the nearest even number when it's exactly halfway between two numbers.  (This is useful for a number of reasons, primarily because it doesn't bias up or down on average, tending to balance out rounding error.)

Just call `setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` for the behavior you describe.